# MongoDB group by count based on condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongodb-query, nosql-aggregation

I have the below mongo DB schema:

```
 {
    "_id" : "5b76c3c037548390fdb5b40e",
    "userId" : "4601",
    "modified" : ISODate("2018-08-21T19:13:43.301+05:30"),
    "rStatus" : "started",
},
{
    "_id" : "5b76c3c037548390fdb5b40e",
    "userId" : "13",
    "modified" : ISODate("2018-08-21T19:13:43.301+05:30"),
    "rStatus" : "completed",
},
........
```

There is a need to get data group by modified date and count of rStatus field, eg

```
{
    modified:"2018-08-21",
    count :{"completed":1,"ongoing":4}
},
{
    modified:"2018-07-23",
    count :{"completed":2,"ongoing":5}
},
```

I am using $group but its count by modified date only not by the inner keys' values.

Comment: this might be the answer `db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
   "_id": { "$dateToString": { "date": "$modified", "format": "%Y-%m-%d" }},
   "completed": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$rStatus", "completed" ] }, 1, 0 ] }}
 }}
])`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, Thanks, Its working

Answer (score 5):

You can use below aggregation in 3.6.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
{"$group":{
  "_id":{
    "date":{"$dateToString":{"date":"$modified","format":"%Y-%m-%d"}},
    "rstatus":"$rStatus"
  },
  "count":{"$sum":1}
}},
{"$group":{
  "_id":"$_id.date",
  "count":{"$mergeObjects":{"$arrayToObject":[[["$_id.rstatus","$count"]]]}}
}}])
```